# Using a List of Indexes to Grab Values in Another List

Tags: python

I have two lists, one containing a set of index points that I would like to pull from a second list.

```
index_values = [3, 3, 6, 7]
```

A list of ten numbers

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I'm trying to get the result to print the numbers at the `3, 3, 6, and 7` indexes in the second list.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: use a `for index in index_values:` loop.

Comment: Okay I was overthinking it way too much.

    'for index in index_values:'
        'print(numbers[index])'

does the job fine. Thank you

I can't work out the formatting

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternatives the way I see it.

#### String join with list comprehension

```
s = ', '.join([str(numbers[idx]) for idx in index_values]) # or '\n' for newlines
print(s)
```

#### Loop

```
for idx in index_values:
    print(numbers[idx])
```

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly sure OP means `3, 3, 6, and 7 indexes` as comma-separated but it could be.

Comment: Your original code had no separator, that's almost certainly not what he wants